A basic question about loop gain and stability
I read that we want to avoid loop gain of -1 to avoid instability in opamps.
But does that mean loop gain of -2 or -50 is fine as long as loop gain is never -1?

Isnt it still positive feedback when loop gain< -1 such as -5 which becomes +5

At first, speaking about a certain value for the "loop gain", you should define (for yourself) which definition you want to apply - because, unfortunately, some authors define the loop gain as "A * beta" (without the phase inversion for neg. feedback) and some others are using "-A * beta". To me. the last expression makes more sense because the loop gain should be negative for negative feedback.

Jim Williams writes on page 377 of Analog Circuit Design that, "As a rule, if $A,\beta$ is equal to or more negative than -1.0, the circuit will tend to be unstable; this can happen if the sum of the phase shifts of $A$ and $\beta$ is $180^\circ$ for frequencies at which the gain magnitude is greater than 1, or vice versa."

The point of feedback is to adjust the gain of the amplifier so that gain doesn't increase drastically with increase in input voltage. This is achieved with negative feedback or with a 180 degrees phase shift of loopgain. Assuming your transfer function is like \$\frac{A}{1+ Aβ}\$ and if the loopgain, Aβ = -1, the amplifier would oscillate which means that there would be output even when the input is zero and hence the amplifer would be unstable. At this point, the circuit becomes an oscillator. In all other cases, the output is either greater or lesser than input depending on Aβ and its phase.
Frequency of the input signal is also important because opamps usually have a cutoff frequency of about 1 to 10 MHz after which there is attenuation of output. Look at a term called Gain-bandwidth product in your opamp datasheet to see at which frequencies your amplifier can amplify signals.

Many (most) opamps are designed to be unity-gain stable.
Some are not - take for example the OP37 which is stable for gain magnitude greater than -5. Photo taken from Analog Devices data sheet:

This graph is purposely terminated a bit after 10 MHz, before open-loop gain drops to 0 dB, because phase at that point would have passed through the -180 degree point. If you tried to run this opamp at low gain, it would oscillate somewhere above 10 MHz.

On the other hand, a unity-gain stable opamp loses gain at high frequency, so that gain drops below 0 dB before phase approaches -180 degrees.
For example a detailed analysis of LM741 op amp is plotted below:

